# jqGrid Grid as Subgrid formatting challenge

Tags: css, jqgrid

Using http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html as an example, I've got a Grid as Subgrid in an MVC app that functionally works as it should, but the problem is that somewhere CSS is doing some pretty strange things:

1. If I expand the second row, all looks good.
2. If I expand the first row, all still looks good.

But if I change the sequence by reloading the page, then

1. Expand the first row, the subgrid looks good,
2. Expand the second row, now it falls apart.  The first subgrid loses it's pager altogether, and the second grid's childPager_left contents get pushed down, as if some padding got added to the top.

I tried hacking in some jQuery to set the padding to 0 on child_Pager_left in the gridComplete event, but here's what's really weird - Chrome shows that padding is indeed 0 when inspecting the td#childPager_left element, but graphically it has a big fat green border around the top and bottom of the element.

Anyway, I just can't figure out why if I expand the rows in reverse order, all is well, but going top down blows out the pager.  Any kind soul have an idea what the problem is? I read an earlier post about MVC setting CSS default values on tables that caused scroll bars to appear when they shouldn't, and by adding the fix in the post it got rid of the scroll bars - wondering if someone has stumbled across something similar for the subgrid's pager.

*Update in response to Oleg's query:*
Oleg: Thank you for taking a look at this!  I've read so many of your great answers on jqGrid - you do an AMAZING service for the community and we're hugely in your debt!

The links I use, in this order, are:
  Styling:

- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css
- http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.3.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css
- [ bootstrap.css ]
- [ site.css ]

Javascript:

- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js
- http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.2/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js
- http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.2/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js

And to make sure that it didn't have anything to do with using old versions of .js or .css libraries, I did go to the jqGrid site, pulled down the 5.0 version of jqGrid, along with jQuery 1.11 and used those - still behaved the same.

Don't laugh too hard, but here's the code:

This is in the common page layout:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.jgrid.defaults = $.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        datatype: 'json',
        gridview: true,
        height: 'auto',
        ignoreCase: true,
        loadonce: false,
        loadui: "block",
        mtype: 'POST',
        multiboxonly: true,
        rowList: [10, 20, 50],
        rowNum: 20,
        rownumbers: true,
        viewrecords: true
});
```

And this is the javascript in the page:

```
var lastParentGridRowSelected;
var lastChildGridRowSelected;
var grid = $('#list');

DependentDelOptions = {
    onclickSubmit: function(rp_ge, rowid) {
        // reset the value of processing option to true to skip the ajax request
        rp_ge.processing = true;
        DeleteDependent(rowid);

        // use onclickSubmit function as "onclick" on "Delete" button delete row
        grid.jqGrid('delRowData', rowid);
        $("#delmod" + grid[0].id).hide();

        if (grid[0].p.lastpage > 1) {
            // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
            $(grid).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: grid[0].p.page }]);
        }

        return true;
    },
    processing: true
};

EmployeeDelOptions = {
    onclickSubmit: function(rp_ge, rowid) {

        rp_ge.processing = true;
        DeleteEmployee(rowid);

        grid.jqGrid('delRowData', rowid);
        $("#delmod" + grid[0].id).hide();

        if (grid[0].p.lastpage > 1) {
            // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
            $(grid).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: grid[0].p.page }]);
        }

        return true;
    },
    processing: true
};


$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '/User/EmployeeMaintenance/GetEmployeesForGrid',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Last Name', 'First Name', 'Salary', '# Dependents', 'Total Benefit Cost', 'Total Discounts', 'Total Benefit Deductions', ''],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', key: true, index: 'Id', width: 240, align: 'left', editable: false, editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidden: true },
            { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 200, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30 },
                editrules: { required: true } },
            { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 200, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30 },
                editrules: { required: true } },
            { name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary', width: 90, align: 'right', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30, defaultValue: @Model.DefaultSalary },
                    editrules: { number: true, minValue: 0 }, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: '$', thousandsSeparator: ',' } },
                { name: 'DependentCount', index: 'DependentCount', width: 90, align: 'right', editable: false },
                { name: 'TotalBenefitCost', index: 'TotalBenefitCost', width: 130, align: 'right', editable: false, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: '$', thousandsSeparator: ',' } },
                { name: 'TotalDiscounts', index: 'TotalDiscounts', width: 100, align: 'right', editable: false, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: '$', thousandsSeparator: ',' } },
                { name: 'EmployeeDeduction', index: 'EmployeeDeduction', width: 150, align: 'right', editable: false, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: '$', thousandsSeparator: ',' } },
                { name: 'CustomActions', index: 'CustomActions', width: '80', align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: {
                        keys: true,
                        delOptions: EmployeeDelOptions,
                        onSuccess:  function () {
                            $(grid).trigger('reloadGrid');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],

            afterInsertRow: function(rowid, rowdata, rowelem) { $(grid).jqGrid.trigger('reloadGrid'); },
            caption: 'Employees',
            editurl: $("#___ActionUpdateEmployee").val(),
            footerrow: true,
            gridComplete: function() { ParentGridComplete(); },
            onSelectRow: function(id) { ParentGridRowSelected(id) },
            pager: $('#pager'),
            subGrid: true,
            subGridRowColapsed: function(subgridId, rowId) { SubGridRowCollapsed(subgridId, rowId) },
            subGridRowExpanded: function(subgridId, rowId) { SubGridRowExpanded(subgridId, rowId) },
            userDataOnFooter : true
        }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: true, edit: false }, {}, {},
            EmployeeDelOptions, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false });

        $('.ui-icon-refresh').click(function() {
            $(grid).jqGrid.trigger('reloadGrid');
        });


    function ChildGridRowSelected(id) {
        if (id && id !== lastChildGridRowSelected) {
            // cancel editing of the previous selected row if it was in editing state.
            if (typeof lastChildGridRowSelected !== "undefined") {
                $(grid).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastChildGridRowSelected);
            }
            lastChildGridRowSelected = id;
        }
    };

    function ParentGridComplete() {
        var iCol = 0;
        $(grid).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")")
            .each(function() {
                $("<div>", {
                            title: "Custom",
                            mouseover: function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); },
                            mouseout: function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); },
                            click: function(e) { alert("'Custom' button is clicked in the rowis=" + $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id") + " !"); }
                        }
                    ).css({ "margin-right": "5px", float: "left", cursor: "pointer" })
                    .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-custom")
                    .append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span>')
                    .prependTo($(this).children("div"));
            });
        $('.ui-icon-search').hide();
    }

    function ParentGridRowSelected(id) {
        if (id && id !== lastParentGridRowSelected) {
            // cancel editing of the previous selected row if it was in editing state.
            if (typeof lastParentGridRowSelected !== "undefined") {
                $(grid).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastParentGridRowSelected);
            }
            lastParentGridRowSelected = id;
            // close all child grids
            $('div[id^="list_"]').html('');
            $(grid).trigger('reloadGrid');
        }
    };

    function SubGridRowExpanded(subgridId, rowId) {
        var subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";
        var dataId = $(grid).jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'Id');
        var pagerId = 'childPager'; // "p_" + subgridTableId;

        jQuery("#" + subgridId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "' class='scroll'></table>");
        $("#"+subgridId).html("<table id='"+subgridTableId+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pagerId+"' class='scroll'></div>");
        jQuery("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
            url: "/User/EmployeeMaintenance/GetDependentsForGrid/" + dataId,
            colNames: ['Id', 'Last Name', 'First Name', 'Active?', ''],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', key: true, index: 'Id', width: 100, editable: false, editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidden: true },
                { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 200, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30 },
                    editrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'FirstName', index: 'Firstname', width: 200, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30 },
                    editrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'IsActive', index: 'IsActive', width: 60, align: 'center', editable: true,  formatter: 'checkbox', edittype: "checkbox",
                    editoptions: { value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes" }, stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ":All;true:Yes;false:No" } },
                { name: 'CustomActions', index: 'CustomActions', width: '80', align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: {
                        keys: true,
                        delOptions: DependentDelOptions,
                        onSuccess:  function () {
                            $(grid).trigger('reloadGrid');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            afterInsertRow: function(rowid, rowdata, rowelem) { $(grid).trigger('reloadGrid'); },
            caption: 'Dependents for ' + $(grid).jqGrid('getCell', dataId, 'FirstName') + ' ' + $(grid).jqGrid('getCell', dataId, 'LastName'),
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            editurl: $("#___ActionUpdateDependent").val() + "?EmployeeId=" + dataId,
            gridComplete: function() {
                ParentGridComplete();
                $('div[id^="gbox_list_"]').css('width', '80%').css('margin-right', '15px').css('padding-bottom', '15px').css('border', '0');
                $('#childPager_left').css('padding', '0');
            },
            onSelectRow: function(id) { ChildGridRowSelected(id) },
            pager: $('#' + pagerId),
        }).jqGrid('navGrid', "#" + pagerId, { edit: false, add: true }, {}, {},
            DependentDelOptions, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false });
    }

    function SubGridRowCollapsed(subgridId) {
        $('#childPager_left').css('padding', '0');
    }

    function DeleteDependent(rowId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#___ActionDeleteDependent").val(),
            data: { dependentId: rowId },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    $("#divSuccess").html("Record Deleted.");
                    $("#divSuccess").show();
                    $(grid).trigger('reloadGrid');
                } else {
                    $("#divError").show();
                    $("#divError").html(data.Message);
                    $("#divSuccess").hide();
                }
            },
            error: function(req, status, error) { $("#divError").html("<span style='color: red'>An error occured: " + error + "</span>"); }
        });
    }

    function DeleteEmployee(rowId) {
        var id = $(grid).jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'Id');

        $.ajax({
            url: $("#___ActionDeleteEmployee").val(),
            data: { employeeId: id },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    $("#divSuccess").html("Record Deleted.");
                    $("#divSuccess").show();
                } else {
                    $("#divError").show();
                    $("#divError").html(data.Message);
                    $("#divSuccess").hide();
                }
            },
            error: function(req, status, error) { $("#divError").html("<span style='color: red'>An error occured: " + error + "</span>"); }
        });
    }

// This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
function htmlEncode(value) {
    var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
    return encodedValue;
}
`
```

Oleg, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You should append your question with the JavaScript code which you use. Especially important to know the code of `subGridRowExpanded` callback where you create the subgrid. It could be important to know which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or old jqGrid in version <=4.7) and in version you use.

Comment: Thanks very much Oleg - question edited to provide the additional info.